# How to dismiss/accept Device Location Popup on Android devices - Selenium with Browser stack

Tags: java, android, selenium, browserstack

I am stuck with this issue from past some days. Can anyone please help or provide some idea on how it can be achieved.

**What/Where I am performing:**

1. Browser: Chrome
2. Device: Samsung Galaxy S20
3. Remote: Browser Stack
4. Test: Selenium with Java connecting Browser Stack

I  have tried many ways to dismiss the location popup appearing post navigating to the URL, but each time Selenium tests doesn't even dismiss or recognise that alert. Below is the picture of the device location popup I am receiving upon navigation:

[image]

**Code that I have tried:**

**Capabilities:**

```
    caps.setCapability("os_version", "10.0");
    caps.setCapability("device", "Samsung Galaxy S20");
    caps.setCapability("realMobile", "true");
    caps.setCapability("browser", "Chrome");
    caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
    caps.setCapability("browserstack.console", "errors");
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    caps.setCapability("name", scenario);
```

I have seen at many places to add "Autograntpermissions". Tried that as well, but didn't work

```
caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
```

I have tried the usual switching to an alert and dismissing it or accepting it but it doesn't work either. Throws "No Such Alert"

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

I thought, maybe this might work, by adding a profile, but it doesn't seem to detect as well and always the popup remains

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map < String, Object > prefs = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
Map < String, Object > profile = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
Map < String, Object > contentSettings = new HashMap < String, Object > ();

contentSettings.put("geolocation", 1);
profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", contentSettings);
prefs.put("profile", profile);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
//... other capabilities
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert is triggered by JS on the webpage but is displayed in the `NATIVE_APP` context. Any alert that's not part of the webpage usually shows up in the NATIVE context.

This alert needs to be handled via Appium as mentioned here:

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/handle-permission-pop-ups#handle-know-your-location-pop-up

```
driver.switch_to.context('NATIVE_APP')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//android.widget.Button[@text='Allow']").click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, Thank you. I tried with "driver.switchTo().context()" but seems like "context()" isn't present in Java for SwitchTo(). Can you please provide some idea on how this can be achieved?

Is this "AndroidDriver" or "RemoteDriver" ?

Comment: I got it. Thank you Shawn. Accepted your answer